# Get list of all elements from search result in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

[image]

I am trying to find list of all anchor elements, which I got during search result.

When I try by CSS:

```
List<WebElement> anchors = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul a"));
```

I am getting many results.

When I try by XPATH:

```
By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/header/div/form/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/a[1]
```

I'm getting only one.

I need all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all anchor elements have the href start with "/products...", if so, please try this xpath:

```
By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, '/products')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us analyze what happened with your code trials :

- When you tried :

  ```
  List<WebElement> anchors = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul a"));
  ```

  You got back **133** matching nodes because where ever an `<a>` tag followed by `<ul>` was found that was added to the `List`. We don't need that actually.
- When you tried :

  ```
  By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/header/div/form/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/a[1]
  ```

  As the `xpath` is an `absolute xpath` with an index `[1]` you get back only one element.

### Solution :

Once you key in the text **`cetaphi`** within the `Search Box` you will find **7** search results within the [**`View Port`**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp). To get the list of all anchor elements within the `Search Results` you can use the following code block :

```
    List<WebElement> anchors = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='clerk-livesearch-title' and contains(text(),'Products')]//following::a/div[@class='clerk-live-item']//div/p"));      
    for (WebElement ele:anchors)
        System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

> **Note** : There are certain other `div` and `ul` with **`id`** attribute set as **`__clerk-1-442699327`**, **`__clerk-__clerk-13-460558980`** etc and they seems to be dynamic. Hence those must be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is to get all the links in the suggestions list. I'm assuming you want to ignore the CATEGORIES link(s) and only get link to products.

There are several ways you can get this. One way is to find the `UL` that has an ID... it's the only one (currently) on the page. You can use the CSS selector below. This is looking for all `A`s that are direct descendants to any `UL` that contains any ID.

```
ul[id] > a
```

Another way, and probably safer, is to not rely on the fact that the `UL` is the only `UL` on the page that has an ID. We can find these elements using the container for the suggestions dropdown and then find the `A`s in the `UL`. The `DIV` that is the container for the suggestions dropdown is

```
<div class="clerk-live-search-container" id="__clerk-2-318441846" style="...">
```

That ID changes each time so we can't rely on it. There are also a number of other IDs on the page that start with `__clerk` so we can't use that either. This `DIV` does have a unique class on it, `class="clerk-live-search-container"`, so we can use that. We can start with this `DIV` and then find the `UL` that contains all the `A`s we want. The CSS selector is below.

```
div.clerk-live-search-container ul > a
```

Both selectors above work but I would probably use the 2nd one because I think it's less likely to break in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

`By.xpath(".//a[contains(@href,'products')]");`

Answer (score 0):

First get all anchor elements and keep them on a `WebElement` list. Then find the link address using `getAttribute("href")` in the loop. You can use like below:

```
List<WebElement> allAnchors = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.clerk-live-search-container > div > ul > a"));
for (WebElement eachAnchorElem : allAnchors) {
    String link = eachAnchorElem.getAttribute("href");
    //System.out.println(link);
}
```

You can use to keep the link adrress in the `String array` or `list`

Comment: @ngk123 hey bro! did it work for you? Please let me know your feedback.